How would you fill a gap between the foundation wall and sidewalk?
How would you fill this gap, this spot in my driveway gets a lot of water. My only concern is that caulk will not be able to fill that spot and the other concern is that the hydraulic cement will be difficult to bond to the small space.



That's a tough situation. To effectively stop water flow into the foundation wall you need to either seal the entire wall or create a barrier to the sidewalk, including at the ends. The context isn't shown, but you might consider cutting the sidewalk back, making repairs, then backfilling with pavers or washed rock.
For the repair, something like a trowelable caulk might do. If you look at commercial buildings constructed of precast concrete panels you'll see this at joints between panels and along the base where pavement abuts.
You could also do a combination of both masonry and caulk--fill the deeper voids with mortar or patch compound, then create a seal against the sidewalk.

What kind of mortar would you recommend?  I thought of hydraulic cement since it expands

You don't need it to expand.  If all you want to do is prevent water intrusion, you need to first solve that vertical crack in the first pic.  A concrete crack filler sealant is probably the way to go.  Then get some backer rod and stuff it in the bigger gaps, and cover with more sealant.

People (including myself) keep forgetting that the right solution is often to use backer rod to fill most of a space, so caulk only has to bridge a much more reasonable surface layer.
